# How to preload content with rel="preload" and Angular's hashed filenames?

Tags: html, angular, preload

Currently a mobile performance tool reports a very bad score for my website because some font files are loaded really late after the site has almost completely initialised. This tool recommends me to use the `rel="preload"` link to preload those font files. The problem is that in the production environment Angular's filesnames contain a content hash, so `my-font.woff` becomes `my-font.<some-hash>.woff`.

Is there a way to circumvene this and preload `my-font.<some-hash>.woff`, without disabling file hashing, because file hashing offers some advantages when detecting stale cache files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your requirement, you should go for [preload-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/preload-webpack-plugin).

Follow the documentation to know more about its working.

In your scenario, it can be used like this -

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
  new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
    rel: 'preload',
    as(entry) {         
      if (/\.woff$/.test(entry)) return 'font';         
    }
  })
]
```

You will have to add this plugin and this code to the application and Webpack configs respectively. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Is there any way to do this in Angular without ejecting webpack?

Comment: You can do it by just adding rel="preload" to the font tags statically, but then you will have to remove hashing. Dynamically webpack is the only solution.

Comment: Ok, and are there any significant downsides to ejecting webpack?

Comment: No, there aren't any downsides. It just involves some extra steps.

Comment: This really helped, thanks. I couldn't figure out how to make the more popular plugin, "webpack-font-preload-plugin" handle hashes.

Comment: Is this the only way to do this by this date?